# How can I get the clusters CIDR in a pod?

Tags: kubernetes

How can I use the cluster CIDR (the ip address range containing all pod ip addresses) inside a pod? *(Autmoatically, without putting it manually in an environment variable, ConfigMap or anywhere else.)*

Exampel of what I would like to:

```
env:
  - name: CLUSTER_CIDR
    valueFrom: # ??? does a configMap like this exist ??? Or any other source for clusterCidr?
      configMap:
       key: clusterCidr
       name: ...
```

my best partial solution:

```
  - name: POD_IP
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: status.podIP

  - name: GUESSED_CLUSTER_CIDR
    value: $(POD_IP)/16
```

I can find clusterCidr inside the configMap `full-cluster-state` in namespace `kube-system` somewhere in the value of key `full-cluster-state`. But this value is a *string* containing json, and it looks vendor specific (in `currentState.rkeConfig.services.kubeController.clusterCidr`). *I can not extract part of the the value in deployment.yaml. And I prefer to have a vendor independent solution.*

I have not idea where to find ComponentConfig mentioned in related issues and do not even know if it is in alpha still.

---

related k8s issues (all closed without (clear) fixing):

- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25533
- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/46508

About finding the CIDR of the cluster manually:

- [How do you find the cluster & service CIDR of a Kubernetes cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190607/how-do-you-find-the-cluster-service-cidr-of-a-kubernetes-cluster)
- old about finding it programmatically: [Kubernetes - Find out service ip range CIDR programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154425/kubernetes-find-out-service-ip-range-cidr-programatically)
- using the CIDR for trusted proxy, what I want to: [Kubernetes: add ingress internal ip to environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694851/kubernetes-add-ingress-internal-ip-to-environment)

Comment: Not sure if I got what you want to achieve. As you have ConfigMap with Cidrs why you wont use it as its described in [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/). Also as you have json output you can open if with YAML output using `-o yaml`. You can also create own configmap from file or some values.

Comment: I extended the question with info why I can not use the mentioned config map and that I look for a vendor independent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Im afraid there is no **vendor independent** solution for this. Also `ComponentConfig` is still an `alpha feature` so there is not enough proper documentation.

However, the best thing right now (even if it's not universal) is to use:

`$ kubectl cluster-info dump | grep -m 1 cluster-cidr`

Then you can create a new `ConfigMap` with the cluster `CIDR` value that was outputted and then refer to it in the pod as in [this docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-a-container-environment-variable-with-data-from-a-single-configmap).

Even if the concept is the same, you will have to apply a different approach in different environments. Unfortunately, as of today there is no single solution.

As for the additional information, I have already made a small comparison between `Kubeadm` and `Google Kubernetes Engine` about CIDR. You can check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847788/inquiring-pod-and-service-subnets-from-inside-kubernetes-cluster) for more information.

Comment: What I want is to get the value automatically in the pod. (No manual putting it in an environment variable, ConfigMap or whatever. ) The answer is it does not work currently. (My partial solution GUESSED_CLUSTER_CIDR seems to be the closest of what I want.)